# Loading secrets and application properties in Configuration Provider

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-keyvault

Am planning to create a new WEBAPI (Azure App Services WEBAPP) on .Net Core 3.1 . Would like to load all the keyvault secrets and the Application Properties key values into same config. Below is how I found out how to get secrets into config but how do we also get the Application Properties loaded as well

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        var builtConfig = config.Build();
        var vaultName = builtConfig["VaultName"];
        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
            async (authority, resource, scope) =>
            {
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(false);
                var token = credential.GetToken(
                    new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                        new[] { "https://vault.azure.net/.default" }));
                return token.Token;
            });
        config.AddAzureKeyVault(
            vaultName,
            keyVaultClient,
            new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
    });
```

Comment: what Application Properties? you mean in appsettings.json? They should be included by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean app settings values, they should be included by default as Nestenius mentioned in comments. And you can get the value by the code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"]
```